# What are PyGame sprites, and what do they do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, sprite

I've found dozens of tutorials on how and when to use sprites, but I still don't really know what they are or what they do.
The default idea seems to be that you subclass the `pygame.sprite.Sprite` class and add `rect` and `image` attributes to the class.
But why do I need to subclass the `Sprite` class, how does it affect my code?
I can just do this anyways:

```
class MySprite:  # No subclassing!
    def __init__(self, image):
        self.image = image
        self.rect = image.get_rect()
```

And it seems to work just fine.
I also tried going through the source code, but [couldn't find a sprite file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMdwS.png).

Comment: You'll find the source code of the `Sprite` class in the [`sprite.py` file](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/src/8bdcd449963fd969c2609dea7134f52d1944ad0f/lib/sprite.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sprites are just objects in a game that can interact with other sprites or anything else.  These can include characters, buildings, or other in game objects.

The reason that there is a subclass for Sprites is more of a convenience.  When an object inherits from the `sprite.Sprite` class they can be added to a sprite group.

Example:

```
import pygame

class car(sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        sprite.Sprite.__init__() # necessary to initialize Sprite class
        self.image = image # insert image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect() #define rect
        self.rect.x = 0 # set up sprite location
        self.rect.y = 0 # set up sprite location
    def update(self):
        pass # put code in here

cars = pygame.sprite.Group()# define a group

pygame.sprite.Group.add(car())# add an instance of car to group
```

I cannot add sprites to sprite groups unless they inherit from the sprite class.  This is useful because I can now do things like update all the sprites in the group and draw them all with one function:

```
cars.update() #calls the update function on all sprites in group
cars.draw(surface) #draws all sprites in the group
```

I can also use groups for collision detection:

```
# check to see if sprite collides with any sprite in the car group
collided = pygame.sprite.Sprite.spritecollide(sprite, cars, False)
```

> note: In the above code `pygame.sprite.Sprite.spritecollide` returns a list.

In conclusion, the sprite class is useful for handling lots of sprites that would otherwise take more code to manage.  The `Sprite` class provides a universal set of variables that can be used to define sprites.

Answer (score 2):

When you subclass, you inherit the methods and functions in the class. The pygame.sprite class contains many pre-written methods that you can call upon without you having to manually re-code everything.

If you decide to create an orphaned/independent MySprite class as you did above, you won't be able to use any of the pre-written code. As long as you're okay with fully fleshing out all of your class's functions on your own, that's fine.